# A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client : Which solution

Tags: asp.net, validation, exception, xss, html-encode

I have a web application using aspx pages.
First, I wanted to use `Server.HtmlEncode(value)` whhen displaying the value in a `LabelledTextBox`

```
public interface ILabelledControl
{
    bool ReadOnly { get; set; }
}

[DefaultProperty("Text")]
[ToolboxData("<{0}:ServerControl1 runat=server></{0}:ServerControl1>")]
public class LabelledTextBox : TextBox, ILabelledControl
{
    //public Unit EditableWidth { get; set; }
    public Unit ReadOnlyWidth { get; set; }

    protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        if (this.ReadOnly)
        {
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lbl = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label();
            foreach (string att in this.Attributes.Keys)
                lbl.Attributes.Add(att, this.Attributes[att]);
            lbl.Text = this.Text;
            lbl.ForeColor = ForeColor;
            //lbl.Width = this.Width;
            if (ReadOnlyWidth != null)
                lbl.Width = ReadOnlyWidth;
            lbl.CssClass = CssClass;
            lbl.ID = this.ID;
            lbl.RenderControl(writer);
        }
        else
        {

            base.Render(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

The value `<script>alert("hello")</script>` was displayed but the script was executed.

Afterward, I wanted to try another solution which was to handle the exception

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client
```

to stay on the same page containing the form and displaying an error message on the top with a generic message like "Please be sure that all input does not contain characters like '<' or '>'"

**Solution 1** : What am I doing wrong ?

**Solution 2 :** How can I handle this exception and stay on the same page with the filled in form

**General :** Which solution is the best ?

Thx !

Answer (score 0):

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the
>   client

You see this server exception because user enters HTML tag (such as < >) inside **Textbox** control, and submits the form.

There is nothing you can prevent it at server-side. However, you can create a client-side validation script, and warn the user or strip out the tags.

For example,

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
     ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server"    
     ControlToValidate="MyTextBox"
     ErrorMessage="Please do not enter HTML tags." 
     ValidationExpression="<(.|\n)*?>">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

> The value alert("hello") was displayed but the script
>   was executed

This is opposite of above scenario. Server renders Script tag to browser.

In order to prevent it, as you said you want to encode the string using [HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz(v=vs.110).aspx) before rending it.

```
lbl.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(this.Text);
```

Comment: 1) How can I create a client-side validation ? Which characters should I remove ? There is a lot of characters that can be dangerous, am I wrong ?
2) I tried to use HtmlEncode - the value is displayed but still executed

Comment: 1) I updated the first answer. 2) HtmlEncode is enough. Please test it in  standard TextBox control first instead of custom server control.